# VBA - To read a cell from one worksheet and input some information into the next worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Good DAy All,

Its my first time here, great to meet you guys.

I hope to create a spreadsheet that allows to calculate payroll in a restaurant.

The following entails what i hope to do, but sadly i know nuts of how to go about doing it as i have no experience in VBA at all.

1) To create spread sheet A with one cell to allow admin to input staff' ID. (For eg: SXXXXXXXX)

2) To create 2 buttons, one is for checking in, another or checking out.

3) the moment staff checks in, excel via VBA will miraculously forward admin to sheet B, which will dynamically indicate the date/time of check in.

Could someone please help me over here?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Are we actually talking about different worksheets in the same workbook, or are you creating a completely new file for "B"?

Comment: Yesh, different worksheets in the same work book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:

1. create a custom toolbar with two icons for check-in and check-out
2. the check-in button links to a dialog with one field "Staff ID", plus [OK] and [Cancel] buttons
3. on pressing the OK button a routine "do_the_needful" is fired

Comment: if you need more help on what Sub CheckIn() should do, just write back